I am looking for a vba code to count rows in a specific SAP screen
I use a script in Excel to read various data from an SAP equipment master and transfer it from SAP to Excel spreadsheet.
At some point in the script I come to the Document TAB and want to count the number of rows that are there.
Screenshot

I would like to incorporate counting the lines present on the screen somewhere in my existing script without having to create a new sub.
I have tried a few things, but I can't seem to get it to work

I see nothing like an Excel sheet nor a data neither a script to inspect.  How do you expect one to help you? Please read this.... How do I ask a good question?
